# How to make combination of CSS classes using SASS mixin?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

```css
@mixin box-default {
    $box: &;
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 16px;
    
    &--sm {
        padding: 8px;
    }
    
    &--dark {
        background-color: darkgrey;
    }
    
    &--sm &--dark {
        padding: 4px;
    } 
}

.test-box {
    @include box-default;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-box--sm test-box--sm">TEST</div>
```

Is it possible somehow to make CSS styles below?

```
.test-box--sm.text-box--dark
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is

```
&--sm#{#{$box}--dark} {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

or

```
&--sm#{&}--dark {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

the result css will be

```
.test-box--sm.text-box--dark
```